# How can I remove page number from some pages in word 2019?

Tags: microsoft-word

In the first few pages of my report, I have a figures table, contact tables and stuff like that which I don't want to have page numbers in.

I've added a section break in the last page of the section mentioned above but they still count when I add page numbers.

Comment: Do I understand right that you have isolated some pages in a section whose pages you don't want to be counted in the general document? If this section is at the start of the document you may just start the count of the next section from `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have a bunch of numbered pages, then one or more pages that aren't numbered, and then more numbered pages. A way to do this is, indeed, with sections. Let's say you have a 10-page document, with 5 numbered pages, then 2 unnumbered pages of tables, and then 3 more numbered pages. You'd insert a new-page section break after the first 5 pages and another new-page section break after the 2 pages of tables. That would give you 3 sections. Then you'd turn on page numbering for the first and third sections but turn it off for the second section. And, for the third section, you'd do as cybernetic.nomad suggests, but instead of having it start at page 1, you'd tell it to start at page 6, since you want the 2-page section of tables not to be numbered. Unless you want those pages to count as part of your total number of pages but simply don't want the page numbers to show up visually. In that case, you'd tell it to start at page 8.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right-click on the field and select "Format Page Number"

[image]

2. At the bottom of the dialog box, select "Start at" and type in "1" (assuming that's the first page number you want)

[image]